# CSS for nested id not getting overridden

Tags: html, css

In below code, CSS for `li:after`  is not working in `progressBarSlot`.
The line connecting the circles is not visible after putting it into the slot.

This is my template.

```css
slot {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.top-padded {
  padding-top: 34px
}

.progress-bar-padding {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.left-padded {
  padding-left: 100px
}

.stick-to-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-padding {
  padding-top: 44px
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.progress-bar-box {
  width: 100%;
  align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: AEmb, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #002f36;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #002f36;
  top: 5px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

li.complete:before {
  border-color: #002f36;
  background-color: #002f36;
}

li.active:before {
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="katal wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="kat-row">
      <slot name="headerSlot">
      </slot>
    </div>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="kat-row progress-bar-padding">
        <div id="progress-bar-parent">
            <ul class="progress-bar-box">
                <li> 1 </li>
                <li> 2 </li>
                <li> 3 </li>
                <li> 4 </li>
                <li> 5 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kat-row top-padded">
        <div class="kat-col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-6">
          <slot name="bannerSlot"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot1"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot2"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot3"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot4"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot5"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot6"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot7"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot8"></slot>
          <div class="kat-row top-padded">
            <slot name="navControlSlot"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="top-padded nav-bar">
            <slot name="navSlot"></slot>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-3">
          <slot name="rightVerticalSlot">
          </slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="kat-row footer-padding flex-footer">
    <slot name="footerSlot">
    </slot>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is progress bar:

```css
.progress-bar-box {
  width: 100%;
  align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: AEmb, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #002f36;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #002f36;
  top: 5px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

li.complete:before {
  border-color: #002f36;
  background-color: #002f36;
}

li.active:before {
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress-bar-parent">
  <ul class="progress-bar-box">
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
    <li> 4 </li>
    <li> 5 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add more details to the question, what does not working mean?

Comment: the line connecting the circles is not visible after putting it into the slot.

Comment: Please edit your question so the code can output the issue

Comment: I would add `.progress-bar-box` as ancestor of each of the `li` rules, so `.progress-bar-box li::after`, `.progress-bar-box li`, etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey still not working

Comment: @Huangism You can run the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your z-index needs fixing

Basically, `li:before` needs position relative so you can set the `z-index` to 1 (z-index only works on an element that has position) and `li:after`'s `z-index` needs to be set at 0 so it is visible

```css
slot {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.top-padded {
  padding-top: 34px
}

.progress-bar-padding {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.left-padded {
  padding-left: 100px
}

.stick-to-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-padding {
  padding-top: 44px
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.progress-bar-box {
  width: 100%;
  align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: AEmb, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #002f36;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #002f36;
  top: 5px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 0;
}

li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

li.complete:before {
  border-color: #002f36;
  background-color: #002f36;
}

li.active:before {
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="katal wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="kat-row">
      <slot name="headerSlot">
      </slot>
    </div>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="kat-row progress-bar-padding">
        <div id="progress-bar-parent">
            <ul class="progress-bar-box">
                <li> 1 </li>
                <li> 2 </li>
                <li> 3 </li>
                <li> 4 </li>
                <li> 5 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kat-row top-padded">
        <div class="kat-col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-6">
          <slot name="bannerSlot"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot1"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot2"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot3"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot4"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot5"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot6"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot7"></slot>
          <slot name="bodySlot8"></slot>
          <div class="kat-row top-padded">
            <slot name="navControlSlot"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="top-padded nav-bar">
            <slot name="navSlot"></slot>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="kat-col-md-3">
          <slot name="rightVerticalSlot">
          </slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="kat-row footer-padding flex-footer">
    <slot name="footerSlot">
    </slot>
  </div>

</div>
```